# Add sidebar content to individual jquery ui dialogs drupal 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drupal, drupal-7

I am working on a drupal 7 site and am using the jquery ui dialog module for modal functionality.

I have about 5 dialog (modals) that are launched when the user clicks a link that looks like so

```
<a href="path-to-content" target="[dialog]">ENLARGE</a>
```

The `href` content is linked to images which are pulled into an `iframe` using these lines of code in the jquery_filter_dialog.js

```
// Set dialog URL with ?dialogFeature= parameters.
  url = Drupal.jQueryUiFilter.dialogFeaturesAppendToURL(url, options['dialogFeatures']);

//Create iframe
    $('body').append(
        '<div id="jquery-ui-filter-dialog">' +
            '<div id="jquery-ui-filter-dialog-container">' +
            '<iframe id="jquery-ui-filter-dialog-iframe" name="jquery-ui-filter-dialog-iframe" width="80%" height="100%" marginWidth="0" marginHeight="0" frameBorder="0" scrolling="' + options['scrolling'] + '" src="' + url + '" />' +
            '</div>' +
        '</div>'
    );
```

Now to the main problem - What I want to do is add a sidebar to this iframe with descriptive content (text and buttons to download a pdf) for each of the different dialogs.

The way I have done that so far is a hack where I check the url value and pass in the custom content via variables directly in that js file like so.

```
if(url == 'http://path-to-content-1.jpg?dialogFeatures=protocol=http'){
        sidebarTitle = 'Title 1';
        sidebarDescription = 'Optional Description for Title 1 - Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris nec felis mattis, placerat velit a, consectetur purus.';
        singleDownload = '/sites/default/files/media/path-to-content-1.pdf';
}
if(url == 'http://path-to-content-2.jpg?dialogFeatures=protocol=http'){
        sidebarTitle = 'Title 2';
        sidebarDescription = 'Optional Description for Title 2 - Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris nec felis mattis, placerat velit a, consectetur purus.';
        singleDownload = '/sites/default/files/media/path-to-content-2.pdf';
}
```

And customize the appended html

```
$('body').append(
  '<div id="jquery-ui-filter-dialog">' +
    '<div id="jquery-ui-filter-dialog-container">' +
      '<iframe id="jquery-ui-filter-dialog-iframe" name="jquery-ui-filter-dialog-iframe" width="80%" height="100%" marginWidth="0" marginHeight="0" frameBorder="0" scrolling="' + options['scrolling'] + '" src="' + url + '" />' +
        '<div class="dialog-info-sidebar">' +
            '<h2 class="sidebar-title">' + sidebarTitle + '</h2>' +
            '<p class="sidebar-description">' + sidebarDescription + '</p>' +
            '<div class="download_now btn-blue">' +
            '<a class="views-ajax-processed-processed colorbox-node colorbox-inline init-colorbox-inline-processed cboxElement init-colorbox-node-processed-processed" href="' + singleDownload + '">' + "DOWNLOAD THIS INFOGRAPHIC" + '</a>' +
           '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
     '</div>' +
  '</div>'
);
```

This displays the custom content in each dialog as expected but is obviously horrible practice - I have no idea how to customize this module so that ideally users can enter the title, description, link to download button and other content when they first envoke the use of the dialog using the a tag.

Has anyone worked with customizing this module before?

Comment: Is your question how to work with the module or how to improve your code? You state it works, so it's a bit confusing.

Comment: How to improve the module - my solution is essentially hard coding values and urls directly into the js - I would like the users to be able to do this I guess through a form or directly on the a tag when they set up a dialog in the cms but I do not know how to change this module flexibly to do so.